# Number pattern using nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code which prints a particular number pattern. I want my number pattern to be in perfect triangular arrangement like:

```
a = int(input('Enter number: '))
base = a
while base > 0:
    for j in range(1, a + 1):
        print(' ' * (2 * j - 2), end = '')
        for i in range(1, base + 1):
            print(str(i), end = ' ')
        print()
        base -= 1
```

The output:

```
Enter number: 5
1 2 3 4 5 
  1 2 3 4 
    1 2 3 
      1 2 
        1
```

```
Enter number: 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 
    1 2 3 4 5 
      1 2 3 4 
        1 2 3 
          1 2 
            1
```

The program works fine for numbers < 10 but when I input a number > 10 it gives a distorted pattern. 
For example:

```
Enter number: 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
              1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
                1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
                  1 2 3 4 5 6 
                    1 2 3 4 5 
                      1 2 3 4 
                        1 2 3 
                          1 2 
                            1
```

So is there a way to make the pattern right?

Comment: What is "right"? Please [edit] your question and add your expected output (just the first few rows would do) for that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the same result for two digit numbers, you have to format your string. Here how it also works for two digit results:

```
a = int(input('Enter number: '))
base = a
while base > 0:
    for j in range(1, a + 1):
        print('  ' * (2 * j - 2), end = '')
        for i in range(1, base + 1):
            print('{0:>2}'.format(str(i)), end = '  ')
        print()
        base -= 1
```

Result for 15:

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  
         1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  
             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
                 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  
                     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  
                         1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  
                             1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  
                                 1   2   3   4   5   6   7  
                                     1   2   3   4   5   6  
                                         1   2   3   4   5  
                                             1   2   3   4  
                                                 1   2   3  
                                                     1   2  
                                                         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Some adjustments and [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) will do the trick:

```
a = base = 15
while base > 0:
    for j in range(a):
        print(' ' * 3 * j, end='')
        for i in range(base):
            print(str(i+1).rjust(3), end='')
        print()
        base -= 1

  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
        1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
           1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
              1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
                 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
                    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
                       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
                          1  2  3  4  5  6  7
                             1  2  3  4  5  6
                                1  2  3  4  5
                                   1  2  3  4
                                      1  2  3
                                         1  2
                                            1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `rjust` method of `str`, it does:

> Return a right-justified string of length width. Padding is done using
>   the specified fill character (default is a space).

Simple example usage:

```
numbers = [1, 10, 10, 1000, 10000]
for n in numbers:
    print(str(n).rjust(5))
```

Output:

```
    1
   10
   10
 1000
10000
```

Note that `rjust` requires at least one argument: `width`, if original `str` is shorther than width leading spaces (or other characters if specified) will be added to get str of length equal to `width`, otherwise original `str` will be returned.